# Use variables in Manipulate out of scope

Tags: manipulate

Is there any way to use variables in Manipulate out of scope of Manipulate?
For example,

```
sphereRadius = 12;
sphereCenter = {0, 0, 0};
sphere = Sphere[sphereCenter, sphereRadius];
Manipulate[Graphics3D[sphere], {sphereRadius, 0, 30}]
```

It can be useful if sphereRadius have difficult formula from other variables. If there is no way to do it then I will paste difficult formulas in Manipulate, what is not very good.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Take a look at `LocalizeVariables`.

Comment: @Kuba, thank you very much, it looks like a what I wanted:)

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case where a good solution is to define a function.

```
sphereCenter = {0, 0, 0};
sphere[sphereRadius_] := Sphere[sphereCenter, sphereRadius];
Manipulate[Graphics3D[sphere[s], 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {s, 1, 10}]
```

I added the PlotRange, because otherwise you can't see the ball getting larger and smaller due to the automatic scaling of the plot.

Comment: It's a good way, but it is not suit to my situation, because I have a good "cascade" of computations and if I turn variables to functions then code will turn in "Spaghetti".

Comment: @pisarik -- I'm skeptical. You can of course define a "cascade" of functions. Mathematica does not really distinguish between "variables" and "functions." In any case, you are better off doing as few computations as possible within the `Manipulate`.